# How to open a terminal in Sawfish?

Tags: terminal, freebsd, window-manager

I am running FreeBSD and I installed Xorg and then Sawfish, I got it working and running: a black screen with a black mouse... that is all.  It moves and all but none of the mouse buttons do anything.  So how do I open a terminal while I'm in there?

Answer (score 0):

So, on a fresh installation of sawfish with zero configuration, a user need only press the middle button on a mouse OR both left and right mouse buttons simultaneously to bring up a menu.  In this menu, select customize > SawfishConfig; select Bindings in the left menu; click Add; select a key; choose Run shell command; place "xterm" in the command window.